# OrientDB SQL Check if multiple pairs of vertices are connected

Tags: orientdb

I haven't been able to find an answer for the SQL for this.

Given pairs of vertices (record ids) and edge types between them, I want to check if all pairs exists.

V1 --E1--> V2

V3 --E2--> V4

... and so on. The answer I want is true / false or something equivalent. ALL connections must be present in order to evaluate to true, so at least one edge (of correct type) must exist for each pair.

Pseudo, the question would be:

```
Does V1 have edge <E1EdgeType> to V2?
AND
Does V3 have edge <E2EdgeType> to V4?
AND
... and so on
```

Does anyone know what the orientDB SQL would be to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I did already have one way of checking if one single edge exists between known vertices. It's perhaps not very pretty either, but it works:

```
SELECT FROM (
    SELECT EXPAND(out('TestEdge')) FROM #12:0
) WHERE @rid=#12:1
```

This will return the destination record (#12:0) if an edge of type 'TestEdge' exists from #12:0 to #12:1. However, if I have two of those, how can I query for one single result for both queries. Something like:

```
SELECT <something with $c> LET
    $a = (SELECT FROM (SELECT EXPAND(out('TestEdge')) FROM #12:0) WHERE @rid=#12:1)
    $b = (SELECT FROM (SELECT EXPAND(out('AnotherTestEdge')) FROM #12:2) WHERE @rid=#12:3)
    $c = <something that checks that both a and b yield results>
```

That's what I aim towards doing. Please tell me if I'm solving this the wrong way. I'm not even sure what the gain is to merge queries like this compared to just repeat queries.

Comment: maybe you can try with a javascript function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be useful to you the following query

```
SELECT eval('sum($a.size(),$b.size())==2') as existing_edges
let $a = ( SELECT from TestEdge where out = #12:0 and in = #12:1 limit 1),
    $b = ( SELECT from AnotherTestEdge where out = #12:2 and in = #12:3 limit 1)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, very useful, since it is both extendable to more edges and also shows a way of returning one single boolean. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Given a pair of vertices, say #11:0 and #12:0, the following query will effectively check whether there is an edge of type E from #11:0
 to #12:0

```
select from (select @this, out(E) from #11:0 unwind out) where out = #12:0

----+------+-----+-----
#   |@CLASS|this |out  
----+------+-----+-----
0   |null  |#11:0|#12:0
----+------+-----+-----
```

This is highly inelegant and I would encourage you to think about formulating an enhancement request accordingly at https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues

One way to incorporate the boolean tests you have in mind is illustrated by the following:

```
select from 
  (select $a.size() as a, $b.size() as b
   let a=(select count(*) as e from (select out(E) from #11:0 unwind out)
                                     where out = #12:0),
       b=(select count(*) as e from (select out(E) from #11:1 unwind out)
                                     where out = #12:2))
where a > 0 and b > 0
```

Yes, inelegance again :-(

Comment: Thanks a lot for that example! Is it possible to shape it into a more true/false like result and/or merge it into two (or more) of those examples (queries) you did. I know how to merge queries using LET, I just don't know how to handle the query results where I need to see if each respective query needs to "return true" (ie each query needs to successfully check if the edge exists between the vertices) and at the same time I need to make sure that every one of those queries successfully found an edge to make the whole (outer if you want) query return as "true".

Comment: I actually had another way of finding it out which was somewhat similar to yours, I will update my question with it (if you have comments as to which one is better, please enlighten me). But I still don't know how to modify the return data to be able to do logical checks on several query results at the same time.

Comment: I first saw your update now. This is also a solution. It is also possible to convert the size() to boolean with `$a.size().asBoolean()`. The result would still be an array of booleans. There are tricks to condense it into a single boolean as well though, as the marked answer shows one example of. I agree that it would be nice to have some simpler way to do this. Preferably with an inbuilt function or so, since it feels like something really useful.